# Alembic ignores new model and does not add new table to revision

Tags: python, flask, alembic

How can I make alembic take a new file with a new model into account for a new revision? All the models are in the same directory `/models` but alembic seems to ignore it. How can it be included and tracked by alembic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be imported one way or another when alembic runs, otherwise it won't know about it. You can for example create a `models/__init__.py` file and import your models there.

Basically `migrations/env.py` needs to know about your models. You can import them there as well, but models init is probably easier.

Comment: hello, thanks yeah that is one way. I wanted to avoid importing all models in __init__ but I dont think there is a better option. Either that or import the models directly into env.py which is worse I think.